# AWS Postgresql DB not accepting TCP/IP

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to deploy my django app on the free AWS platform and i'm having issues connecting the app to  AWS postgresql DB, I've setup the DB and django setting file like this

`AWS SETTINGS`

```
host: ecommerce.cxu8zbmvaiut.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
port: `5432`
name: `commerce`
user: `hello-world`
password: `******`
Publicly accessible: `Yes`
```

DJANGO SETTING FILE

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'commerce',
        'USER':config('user'),
        'PASSWORD': config('password'),
        'HOST': config('host'),
        'PORT': config('port')
    }
}
```

but when i try to make migrations from  my AWS console i get this error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection to server at "ecommerce.cxu8zbmvaiut.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.34.128), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

  warnings.warn(
```

Can anyone help to solve this error?

thanks

Comment: What does the security group configuration for the RDS instance look like? Is it accepting connections from the machine running the app?

Comment: yes it is accepts connection from the machine  & I've set it to to be accessed publicly

Comment: Well, obviously it doesn't accept a connection. Did you try connecting with e.g. `psql`?